# Как улучшить приложение?

Tags: android, android-studio, app, android-testing

Возможно вопрос довольно странный, но как улучшить качество приложения. Я имею в виду стабильность работы, практически отсутствие падений, и может что то еще, я просто не все аспекты знаю. Просто на данный момент есть приложение и оно вроде работает но есть чувство что код сыроват. Может как-то можно протестировать на все возможные случаи из жизненного цикла приложения, что бы в итоге получился реально качественный продукт.

Comment: Может стоить дать друзьям, чтобы протестировали, как реальные пользователи.

Comment: Нет, это к сожалению не вариант, потому-что у меня приложение идет для работы с микроконтроллером, а он у меня один. Но все равно спасибо за  совет.

Comment: покрыть unit-тестами?)

Comment: что это? какое-то специальное тестирование?

Comment: @YungBlade Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 4):

Шаги стандартные:

- unit-тесты, для качества кода и уверенности что он делает то что надо
- UI-тесты, для уверенности что пользовательский интерфейс ведет себя как надо и отображает все как надо. Espresso хороший выбор: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/index.html
- Сбор информации о крэшах, чтобы знать что у кого почему падает. Firebase Crashlytics хороший выбор: https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics/